# creating another copy of a xml shape in android during runtime

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an application that has a "palette" with different basic shapes (e.g. circle, rectangle etc) and the user can drag and drop copies of these onto a canvas. My shapes are defined in xml files. At the moment I can move them onto the canvas but then they disappear from the palette(as I'm moving the original view), so I'd need a way to create a new copy of the shapes when the user clicks on one and drags it to the canvas. I've tried searching for solutions and I looked into LayoutInflaters but couldn't get them to work. Are LayoutInflaters the way to go or is there a better solution? 
Please see my code snippet below.

Thanks

in my onDrag() :

```
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    //owner.removeView(view);
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
    View copyview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.drawable.rectangle, null);
    container.addView(copyview);
    copyview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
```

EDIT:

XML for rectangle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <solid android:color="#ffff00ff" />

</shape>
```

logcat:

```
10-18 19:59:12.461: I/dalvikvm(830): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:59:12.741: I/dalvikvm(830): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:59:12.961: I/dalvikvm(830): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:59:13.101: I/dalvikvm(830): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:59:13.372: D/android.widget.GridLayout(830): vertical constraints: y1 - y0 > 160, y2 - y1 > 1038, y2 - y0 < 1038 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y2 - y0 < 1038. 
10-18 19:59:13.481: I/dalvikvm(830): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:59:13.542: I/dalvikvm(830): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:59:13.661: D/gralloc_goldfish(830): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-18 19:59:15.531: D/AndroidRuntime(830): Shutting down VM
10-18 19:59:15.531: W/dalvikvm(830): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class shape
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.neonwizard.shapes.DragActivity$MyDragListener.onDrag(DragActivity.java:68)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:13461)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1155)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1141)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1141)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1141)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1141)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3471)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2620)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.shape
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
10-18 19:59:15.631: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  ... 20 more
10-18 19:59:16.251: I/dalvikvm(830): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:59:16.282: I/dalvikvm(830): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Layout inflaters are 'one' of the ways to go and probably easiest.  What problem did you have - "couldn't get them to work"?

Comment: I should add that the idea is not to "copy" the view, rather create a new one which is the same.  Copying would not be a good idea.

Comment: when I drag and release the shape over the canvas view, the app crashes and I get 

"FATAL EXCEPTION: main

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class shape"

Comment: which part should I put on? All of it won't fit :/
Edit: I put on the line that seems to be the problem above..?

Comment: Please post the entire exception trace - the bit in red.

Comment: Please also show the XML for your rectangle.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! For things like the stack trace, please use the "edit" link below your question, rather than flooding the comments. `<shape>` is not a layout -- it is a type of drawable: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: okay, thank you for your advice and sorry for flooding the comments.
So can I not use LayoutInflater with shapes? How can I do it then? Thank you for your help